# Boost GraphML format

Tags: c++, boost, tinkerpop

Can anybody explain the GraphML format that Boost uses?  It includes a level of indirection that other GraphML writers don't use.  I have included GraphML output from 2 sources, both stemming from the same input data.  I don't understand why Boost appears to use an extra level of indirection with the 'key[0-N]' keywords.  Any cogent explanations are much appreciated.

I am looking for a way to configure Boost to produce output that is similar or identical to the output that Java/Tinkerpop produces, as illustrated in the first example below.  I would like to eliminate the 'key[0-N]' indirection.

First, here is output produced in a Java program that uses the TinkerPop graph library:

```
    <graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.1/graphml.xsd">
        <key id="UnitName" for="node" attr.name="UnitName" attr.type="string" />
        <key id="id" for="node" attr.name="id" attr.type="int" />
        <key id="labelV" for="node" attr.name="labelV" attr.type="string" />
        <key id="EdgeName" for="edge" attr.name="EdgeName" attr.type="string" />
        <key id="labelE" for="edge" attr.name="labelE" attr.type="string" />
        <key id="length" for="edge" attr.name="length" attr.type="long" />
        <key id="sourceport" for="edge" attr.name="sourceport" attr.type="string" />
        <key id="targetport" for="edge" attr.name="targetport" attr.type="string" />
        <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
            <node id="n0">
                <data key="labelV">vertex</data>
                <data key="UnitName">Div:101</data>
                <data key="id">101</data>
            </node>
            <node id="n1">
                <data key="labelV">vertex</data>
                <data key="UnitName">Blow:1</data>
                <data key="id">1</data>
            </node>
            <node id="n2">
                <data key="labelV">vertex</data>
                <data key="UnitName">Div:201</data>
                <data key="id">201</data>
            </node>
            <node id="n3">
                <data key="labelV">vertex</data>
                <data key="UnitName">Blow:2</data>
                <data key="id">2</data>
            </node>
            <node id="n4">
                <data key="labelV">vertex</data>
                <data key="UnitName">Sta:10 Sta10</data>
                <data key="id">10</data>
            </node>
            <node id="n5">
                <data key="labelV">vertex</data>
                <data key="UnitName">Sta:11 Sta11</data>
                <data key="id">11</data>
            </node>
            <node id="n6">
                <data key="labelV">vertex</data>
                <data key="UnitName">IZ:1002</data>
                <data key="id">1002</data>
            </node>
            <node id="n7">
                <data key="labelV">vertex</data>
                <data key="UnitName">Sta:20</data>
                <data key="id">20</data>
            </node>
            <node id="n8">
                <data key="labelV">vertex</data>
                <data key="UnitName">Sta:21</data>
                <data key="id">21</data>
            </node>
            <edge id="e0" source="n0" target="n4">
                <data key="labelE">edge</data>
                <data key="EdgeName">Edge from Div:101 to Sta:10 Sta10</data>
                <data key="length">80</data>
                <data key="sourceport">0</data>
                <data key="targetport"></data>
            </edge>
            <edge id="e1" source="n0" target="n5">
                <data key="labelE">edge</data>
                <data key="EdgeName">Edge from Div:101 to Sta:11 Sta11</data>
                <data key="length">80</data>
                <data key="sourceport">1</data>
                <data key="targetport"></data>
            </edge>
            <edge id="e2" source="n0" target="n6">
                <data key="labelE">edge</data>
                <data key="EdgeName">Edge from Div:101 to IZ:1002</data>
                <data key="length">20</data>
                <data key="sourceport">3</data>
                <data key="targetport"></data>
            </edge>
            <edge id="e3" source="n1" target="n0">
                <data key="labelE">edge</data>
                <data key="EdgeName">Edge from Blow:1 to Div:101</data>
                <data key="length">0</data>
                <data key="sourceport"></data>
                <data key="targetport"></data>
            </edge>
            <edge id="e4" source="n2" target="n7">
                <data key="labelE">edge</data>
                <data key="EdgeName">Edge from Div:201 to Sta:20</data>
                <data key="length">80</data>
                <data key="sourceport">0</data>
                <data key="targetport"></data>
            </edge>
            <edge id="e5" source="n2" target="n8">
                <data key="labelE">edge</data>
                <data key="EdgeName">Edge from Div:201 to Sta:21</data>
                <data key="length">80</data>
                <data key="sourceport">1</data>
                <data key="targetport"></data>
            </edge>
            <edge id="e6" source="n2" target="n6">
                <data key="labelE">edge</data>
                <data key="EdgeName">Edge from Div:201 to IZ:1002</data>
                <data key="length">20</data>
                <data key="sourceport">3</data>
                <data key="targetport"></data>
            </edge>
            <edge id="e7" source="n3" target="n2">
                <data key="labelE">edge</data>
                <data key="EdgeName">Edge from Blow:2 to Div:201</data>
                <data key="length">0</data>
                <data key="sourceport"></data>
                <data key="targetport"></data>
            </edge>
        </graph>
    </graphml>
```

Here is the same data as it appears when i use a the C++ write_graphml() function from the Boost Graph Library:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
      <key id="key0" for="edge" attr.name="EdgeName" attr.type="string" />
      <key id="key1" for="node" attr.name="UnitName" attr.type="string" />
      <key id="key2" for="node" attr.name="id" attr.type="int" />
      <key id="key3" for="edge" attr.name="length" attr.type="long" />
      <key id="key4" for="edge" attr.name="sourceport" attr.type="string" />
      <key id="key5" for="edge" attr.name="targetport" attr.type="string" />
      <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed" parse.nodeids="free" parse.edgeids="canonical" parse.order="nodesfirst">
        <node id="n0">
          <data key="key1">Div:101</data>
          <data key="key2">101</data>
        </node>
        <node id="n1">
          <data key="key1">Blow:1</data>
          <data key="key2">1</data>
        </node>
        <node id="n2">
          <data key="key1">Sta:20</data>
          <data key="key2">20</data>
        </node>
        <node id="n3">
          <data key="key1">Div:201</data>
          <data key="key2">201</data>
        </node>
        <node id="n4">
          <data key="key1">Sta:21</data>
          <data key="key2">21</data>
        </node>
        <node id="n5">
          <data key="key1">Zn:1====Zn:2:1002</data>
          <data key="key2">1002</data>
        </node>
        <node id="n6">
          <data key="key1">Sta:10 Sta10</data>
          <data key="key2">10</data>
        </node>
        <node id="n7">
          <data key="key1">Sta:11 Sta11</data>
          <data key="key2">11</data>
        </node>
        <node id="n8">
          <data key="key1">Blow:2</data>
          <data key="key2">2</data>
        </node>
        <edge id="e0" source="n0" target="n6">
          <data key="key0">Edge from Div:101 to Sta:10 Sta10</data>
          <data key="key3">80</data>
          <data key="key4">0</data>
          <data key="key5"></data>
        </edge>
        <edge id="e1" source="n0" target="n7">
          <data key="key0">Edge from Div:101 to Sta:11 Sta11</data>
          <data key="key3">80</data>
          <data key="key4">1</data>
          <data key="key5"></data>
        </edge>
        <edge id="e2" source="n0" target="n5">
          <data key="key0">Edge from Div:101 to Zn:1====Zn:2:1002</data>
          <data key="key3">20</data>
          <data key="key4">3</data>
          <data key="key5"></data>
        </edge>
        <edge id="e3" source="n1" target="n0">
          <data key="key0">Edge from Blow:1 to Div:101</data>
          <data key="key3">0</data>
          <data key="key4"></data>
          <data key="key5"></data>
        </edge>
        <edge id="e4" source="n3" target="n2">
          <data key="key0">Edge from Div:201 to Sta:20</data>
          <data key="key3">80</data>
          <data key="key4">0</data>
          <data key="key5"></data>
        </edge>
        <edge id="e5" source="n3" target="n4">
          <data key="key0">Edge from Div:201 to Sta:21</data>
          <data key="key3">80</data>
          <data key="key4">1</data>
          <data key="key5"></data>
        </edge>
        <edge id="e6" source="n3" target="n5">
          <data key="key0">Edge from Div:201 to Zn:1====Zn:2:1002</data>
          <data key="key3">20</data>
          <data key="key4">3</data>
          <data key="key5"></data>
        </edge>
        <edge id="e7" source="n8" target="n3">
          <data key="key0">Edge from Blow:2 to Div:201</data>
          <data key="key3">0</data>
          <data key="key4"></data>
          <data key="key5"></data>
        </edge>
      </graph>
    </graphml>
```

We have a conflict between two applications.  The Boost application exports the GraphML initially.  Another application uses JanusGraph/Gremlin/Tinkerpop  to load the GraphML as input and create the graph.  Even though the GraphML is syntactically correct, JanusGraph/Tinkerpop throws an exception when reading the GraphML:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be in protected namespace: edge
       at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.system.SystemTypeManager.isNotSystemName(SystemTypeManager.java:72)
       at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.StandardRelationTypeMaker.name(StandardRelationTypeMaker.java:188)
       at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.StandardRelationTypeMaker.<init>(StandardRelationTypeMaker.java:57)
       at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.StandardEdgeLabelMaker.<init>(StandardEdgeLabelMaker.java:42)
       at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.makeEdgeLabel(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:980)
       at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.getOrCreateEdgeLabel(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:965)
       at org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.addEdge(AbstractVertex.java:163)
       at org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.addEdge(AbstractVertex.java:37)
       at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphml.GraphMLReader.readGraph(GraphMLReader.java:191)
```

I have discovered I can work around this by editing the GraphML, and doing a global search/replace on key0 and replacing it with labelE.  I’m not entirely sure why this works, and obviously I’m trying to avoid this step so our first thought was to get Boost to export that field as “labelE” instead of “key0”.

On a related note, Tinkerpop loads the original GraphML just fine if I’m using the in-memory Tinkergraph.  The exception only occurs when I use JanusGraph as my underlying DB.

Comment: Did you lose interest?

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a way to configure Boost to produce output that is similar or identical to the output that Java/Tinkerpop produces, as illustrated in the first example below. I would like to eliminate the 'key[0-N]' indirection.

You're confusing yourself. The TinkerPop output has exactly the same level of indirection. The only difference is that TinkerPop decides that it knows that the ids for the node and edge data keys *are the same*.

There's no difference whatsoever for the tools that read the XML.

In fact, even the following would be equivalent:

```
<graphml>
    <key id="UnitName" for="node" attr.name="UnitName" attr.type="string" />
    <key id="labelV" for="node" attr.name="labelV" attr.type="string" />
    <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
        <node id="n0">
            <data key="labelV">vertex</data>
            <data key="UnitName">Div:101</data>
        </node>
        <node id="n1">
            <data key="labelV">vertex</data>
            <data key="UnitName">Blow:1</data>
        </node>
    </graph>
</graphml>
```

There's no difference with:

```
<graphml>
    <key id="labelV" for="node" attr.name="UnitName" attr.type="string" />
    <key id="UnitName" for="node" attr.name="labelV" attr.type="string" />
    <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
        <node id="n0">
            <data key="UnitName">vertex</data>
            <data key="labelV">Div:101</data>
        </node>
        <node id="n1">
            <data key="UnitName">vertex</data>
            <data key="labelV">Blow:1</data>
        </node>
    </graph>
</graphml>
```

Yeah, it would be confusing for a *human* reading that XML, but humans do not read that XML.

You really have to ask yourself why it is important to you that these details that are **specified to be irrelevant** matter to you. Most likely, that's not even the case.

Of course, you could be in tough spot, if the tool reading the XML was programmed on the wrong assumptions (a.k.a. "has a bug"). I suggest to look to fix that first.

Otherwise you can try to hack the GraphML writer to not use autogenerated key ids. That won't be too hard, but it does invite trouble (e.g. when there is a name class between edge/node attributes).

Comment: In fact I've tinkered [_sic_] with roundtripping and the only differences I find are actual data differences (boost not writing the `labelV` and `labelE` attributes, and other node names, like `Zn:1====Zn:2:1002`. See for  yourself: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c901bd8e15784c8b